# working on a remote R session

Tags: r, ssh, remote-server

The R session that I am working on is on a remote cluster due to memory contraints and the data is stored remotely.  I am therefore using notepad++ to edit my files and just paste them into my SSH session as I go along.  What is the best way to integrate with the remote session to take advantage of code completion and other things available in editors like RStudio.  Any best practice suggestions about working on remote connections?  I imagine this must be the case for most R users who work with large data sets.

Comment: If you can get your sysadmin to run RStudio Server, it would be great.

Comment: unfortunately that can't happen.. looking for another way.

Comment: how about running emacs/ESS or vim depending on your preference? graphics will be tricky unless you can get X11 forwarding worked out, but everything else should work just fine ...

Comment: interesting suggestion - one problem i have run into with this is the niceness of color coding within my code. can emacs/ess do this?

Comment: Color coding? You mean syntax highlighting?

Comment: yes, sorry didn't know what it was called

Comment: yes, emacs/ESS and vim can both do syntax highlighting.

Comment: There's a plugin for notepad++ that can edit over SFTP according to http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppftp/ - and if SSH works, the SFTP might do too. Emacs is of course a better option - just open /user@host:/path/to/file.R with it (with Tramp installed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: http://www.sciviews.org/_rgui/projects/Editors.html

The famous [**Vim**](http://www.vim.org) editor now also provides syntax highlighting for R. You can get a plugin to integrate R [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1048). For Windows, there is another plugin using R-DCOM [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2991). There is an alternate, multiplatform, plugin here. Also look at the VIM web site, because there are other interesting resources there for R users (see [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Script%3aList_of_R_Project_scripts) for an overview). There is also an R package to better integrate debugging facilites in Vim: [adtdbg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/edtdbg/index.html)